# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rowConfig.uniqueKey` of type `string` supplied to `Table`, expected `object`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I used to use flow like typechecking but now i have to use prop-types i am getting the following issue

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rowConfig.uniqueKey` of type `string`
>   supplied to `Table`, expected `object`.

in flow type, i did the following

```
type Props = {
  columns: {
     [key: string]: {
       key: string,
       label?: string,
     }
   },
   rowConfig?: {
     uniqueKey?: string,
     css?: string,
     onClick?: Function
   },
}
```

and for prop-types, i did the following way but i am getting above error. Why is that so? Because i have used PropTypes.string and it still expects an object.

```
Table.propTypes = {
  columns     : PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      key          : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label        : PropTypes.string,
    })
  ),
  rowConfig  : PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      uniqueKey: PropTypes.string,
      css      : PropTypes.string,
      onClick  : PropTypes.function
    })
  ),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Table.propTypes = {
  columns     : PropTypes.shape({
     key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     label: PropTypes.string,
  }),

  rowConfig  : PropTypes.shape({
     uniqueKey: PropTypes.string,
     css      : PropTypes.string,
     onClick  : PropTypes.function
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Rep isnt high enough to leave a comment. Your component is named Table? Can you give a little more info? (state, etc.) You may need to remove Proptype.objectof on both.